# Calculate percentage of values in regions of Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I found a question on The Data Science Manual -

```
What percentage of the standard normal distribution (Mean = 0, Std Dev = 1) is found in each region? (Z = Z-Score)
(a) Z > 1.13.
(b) Z < 0.18.
(c) Z > 8.
(d) |Z| < 0:5.
```

I know the 68-95-99.7 rule of normal distribution. But I don't know how it is derived. How do I solve this?

Comment: By a Z table. What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Axion004 Is there a function I can integrate to get the value instead?

Comment: @Axion004 I won't have access to a Z-Table in my exam.

Comment: @PrateekNarendra See my answer. There is no way to get an analytic result if you do the integration. However, if you are supposed to calculate the value without a $z$-score table or a calculator (unlikely if you are studying data science), you could keep the first few terms and omit other terms in the Taylor expansion of the Error Function. Though I would see that as an extreme torture.

Comment: Will you have a TI 83/84 type graphing calculator? You can find it on one of these using the normalcdf function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should read [Normal Distribution](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Normal_distribution). The analytic formula of $N(0,1)$ is
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$$
The $68-95-99.7$ rule is actually derived by calculating the area in between $1,2,3$ standard deviation. For $N(0,1)$, $\sigma=1$, $2\sigma=2$, and $3\sigma=3$.

Therefore,
$$1\text{SD}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-1}^1e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx=\left.\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right|^1_{-1}\approx0.682\bar{7}$$
$$2\text{SD}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-2}^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx=\left.\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right|^2_{-2}\approx0.954\bar{5}$$
$$3\text{SD}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-3}^3e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx=\left.\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right|^3_{-3}\approx0.997\bar{3}$$
where erf is the [Error Function](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Error_function).

---

Now consider the intervals of $z$-score you provided. Clearly, $z>1.13$ means integrating from $1.13$ to $+\infty$. Therefore, by simple calculations, you could get

1. $0.129$
2. $0.571$
3. $6.28\times10^{−16}$
4. $0.383$

---

**P.S. If you are studying data science, you should probably use a calculator and plug these intervals in.**